# Отдельная сборка с минимальными отличиями

Tags: android, build, apk

У меня есть проект с несколькими флаверсами, появилась необходимость выпустить отдельную сборку, отличающуюся от одного из флаверсов только одной строчкой, но с другим `appId` и `appLabel`. Делать отдельный флаверс и копировать директорию аналогичного флаверса для того, чтобы изменить одну строчку, как-то не хочется. Что еще можно придумать, чтобы решить данную проблему?

Comment: можно сделать sub dimension, тогда копировать ничего не придется

Answer (score 3):

Если я вас правильно понял, тогда реализовываем в `build.gradle` на уровне `app` или инного модуля для которого нужно выполнить изменения:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "string", "APP_ID", "12313edade-wesd21-ewe"
        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "string", "APP_ID", "7878ew21ewe-wee78-ewe"
        }
}
```

а в месте где его вы используете:

```
BuildConfig.APP_ID // Вернёт вам ваше значение для выбранного варианта
```

Вместо release/debug - можно использовать другие, но базовые лучше не менять.

Для перехода в студии есть BuildVariants (вкладка слева в низу зачастую). После изменения подождите пока соберётся.

[Тут можно ознакомится.](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/gradle.php)

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. В принципе все так, но суть была в том, чтобы не дублировать код. См. мой ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Сделал отдельным флаверсом, для него указал sourceSet на аналогичный флаверс, чтобы не дублировать код. Отличающийся код конфигурирую через buildConfigField.